# Getting error while using json.load function

Tags: json, python-3.x

While trying to convert the following string into JSON object, I got an error. How can I fix it?

```
text = '{ "MonitorGroupGuid": "e8b20230-70b6-4348-36f3e3f", "Description": "Root CA", "IsAll":False}'
JsonObject = json.loads(text)
```

Output:

```
    x = json.loads(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 98 (char 97)
```

Comment: Replacing False with "False" solves this problem. But I need to maintain my string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `False` with `false` (without quotes)

```
text = '{ "MonitorGroupGuid": "e8b20230-70b6-4348-36f3e3f", "Description": "Root CA", "IsAll":false}'
JsonObject = json.loads(text)
print(JsonObject) #{'MonitorGroupGuid': 'e8b20230-70b6-4348-36f3e3f', 'Description': 'Root CA', 'IsAll': False}
```

Comment: There is still a problem associated with this solution. Python recognises only False as a boolean, not false.

Comment: If you try `print(JsonObject["IsAll"] is False)`, it prints `True`. So I think the value is recognized correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use "" for False are use 0/1, but if you want it as a bool object use false without quotes

- "False" datatype is string
- just false datatype bool

  text = '{ "MonitorGroupGuid": "e8b20230-70b6-4348-36f3e3f", "Description": "Root CA", "IsAll":"False"}'
  JsonObject = json.loads(text)
  print(JsonObject)#{'MonitorGroupGuid': 'e8b20230-70b6-4348-36f3e3f', 'Description': 'Root CA', 'IsAll': 'False'}